# how can I apply Datatable jquery on asp.net GridView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, datatables

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdDonationRequests" runat="server" SelectMethod="grdDonationRequests_GetData" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                 AllowPaging="True"  PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast"  PageSize="10" DataKeyNames="DonationRequestID" ItemType="Tayf.Models.DonationRequest"
                                AllowSorting="true" Width="100%" CssClass=" table-striped table-condensed table table-bordered table-hover" meta:resourcekey="grdDonationRequestsResource1">
```

I tried to do this

```
    $(function () {            
         $("#<%=grdDonationRequests.ClientID%>").prepend(
$("thead>/thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable({             
                    });
                });
```

but It gives me an Error 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined`

```
Update:-
```

When I tried this `'$("#<%=grdDonationRequests.ClientID%>").dataTable({ "aaSorting": [] });'` it gives me no error also draw gridview as datatable but display it as a empty

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Can you explain in detail?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri I need to apply datatable jquery plugin on my asp.net gridview, which enable me to search, sort , paging ,... etc

Answer (score 1):

I am in the process of doing this very thing right now. the following code is all that was required to actually convert the gridview to a datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var table = $('#your_gridview_id').DataTable();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function () {            
  $("#<%=grdDonationRequests.ClientID%>").dataTable({ 
  });
});
```

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488985/datatable-plugin-with-asp-net-gridview/29489058#29489058) answer

Comment: When I tried this `'$("#<%=grdDonationRequests.ClientID%>").GridviewFix().dataTable({ "aaSorting": [] });' ` it gives me no error also draw gridview as datatable but display it as a empty